# A society obsessed with olympic games

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I can't seem to google this one: A novel no more recent than a few years ago.

On an Island, a dystopian society obsessed with the Olympic games. The first chapters are strange but not too bad; then begins the descent into horror as we realize that food is only given to the best performing athletes, that losers are beaten up, and eventually that even finding a sexual partner is reduced to a giant disgusting race.

Thanks!

Comment: Must. Read. Holy. Crud.

Comment: Check that book you are looking for is on [this](http://www.utopiaanddystopia.com/dystopian-fiction/dystopian-literature-list/) list:

Comment: Not The Hunger Games, right?

Comment: Not the hunger games, no

Comment: Nothing on this list matches